# notifyDataSetChanged() causes IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, indexoutofboundsexception, notifydatasetchanged

Here's a shortened version of my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ArrayList<String> entry = new ArrayList<String>();
private String[] entryString = new String[11];
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
private ListView entryListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    entryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    int listID = R.layout.entry_layout;
    aa = new EntryAdapter(this, listID, entry);
    entryListView.setAdapter(aa);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_add: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        break;
    }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int rc, int resc, Intent i) {
    super.onActivityResult(rc, resc, i);
    entryString = i.getStringArrayExtra("Entry");
    this.onNewItemAdded(entryString);
}

public void onNewItemAdded(String[] _entry){
    String key = new String();
    key = _entry[0];
    entry.add(key);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();   //Runs without crashing when this is removed.
}
```

The adapter class is,

```
@SuppressLint("Instantiatable")
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private ArrayList<String> entries;
int count;
int resource;
public EntryAdapter(Context _context, int _resource, List<String> _entries){
    //TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(_context, _resource, R.id.key, _entries);
    this.resource = _resource;
    this.entries = new ArrayList<String>(_entries);
    this.count = 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;
        li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        row = li.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    }

    TextView keyView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.key);
    TextView siteView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.site);

    for(int c=0; c<11; c++){
        while(!entries.get(c).toString().equals("")){
            count++;
        }
    }

    keyView.setText(entries.get(position));
    siteView.setText(count + "sources");

    return row;
}
}
```

By commenting the aa.notifyDataSetChanged() call in the MainActivity, the application runs without crashing but throws an

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

when it is not commented.

PS: The XML is perfectly fine.

Edit:

Here's the log

> 03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052): Process: com.FirstClass.alert, PID: 6052
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at com.FirstClass.netalert.EntryAdapter.getView(EntryAdapter.java:66)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14822)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>   03-18 18:38:03.840: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post the full exception stack trace please.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the key = _entry[0] line. Check the entry size before you get the 0 index. The notify dataset changed commented and uncommented is probably just an unhappy coincidence.

Comment: @jvrodrigues I put a toast with the key value and it was fine :/

Comment: What line is `EntryAdapter.getView(EntryAdapter.java:66`

Comment: @MartínMarconcini Sorry I didn't get you? How do I check that?

Comment: What is around line 66 in your `EntryAdapter.java` ?

Comment: Line 66 is the for loop. Thank you for making me look there! After correcting the error I made pointed out by @NaveenDissanayake, it would hang on a blue screen. This has happened a few times before as I was trying to fix the code. Turns out, the while loop in the for runs into an infinite loop.

Comment: Glad you found the problem, lesson learned: Read the stack trace carefully next time. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new ArrayList by calling `new ArrayList<String>(_entries);` your ArrayList in your activity will not be referenced by the ArrayList in your Adapter. So when you change the entry Arraylist in your activity it will not effect the Adapters ArrayList. Either change the constructor to:

```
public EntryAdapter(Context _context, int _resource, List<String> _entries){
    super(_context, _resource, R.id.key, _entries);
    this.resource = _resource;
    this.entries = _entries;
    this.count = 0;
}
```

or change the `onNewItemAdded` to:

```
public void onNewItemAdded(String[] _entry){
    String key = new 
    key = _entry[0];
    aa.add(key);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was solved by implementing the `getCount()` method of my `ArrayAdapter`, which helped the `ArrayAdapter` to know how many objects to call `getView()` for, once the data had changed.

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return data.size();
}
```